# Images shuffle on fast scroll in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am using recyclerview in which I have adapter ,that has 3 types of view holders and I am binding data according to the viewHolder class.For that I am using the method given below to check which type of holder is there for recyclerview item

```
   @Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (mDataset.get(position) == null)
        return VIEW__ITEM_PROGRESS;
    else if (mDataset.get(position).getIsPost())
        return VIEW_ITEM_POST;
    else
        return VIEW__ITEM_CALENDAR;
}
```

Problem is when I am using this and scroll, recyclerview items shuffle and image of one item switch with some random item image and etc. However when I use this

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
}
```

I do not face such issue.
Here are my Creation and Binding methods

```
 // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int VIEW_TYPE) {

    if (VIEW_TYPE == VIEW__ITEM_PROGRESS)
        return new ProgressViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.progressbar, parent, false));
    else if (VIEW_TYPE == VIEW_ITEM_POST)
        return new NewsFeedViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_newsfeed, parent, false));
    else
        return new CalendarViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_calendar, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    if (holder instanceof NewsFeedViewHolder) {
     //Do respective work
     }
```

}
Anybody can help what is work around for that so I can resolve this issue as well as differentiation between viewHolders.

Thanks!

Comment: is your ViewHolder class static ?

Comment: Your images shuffle because the RecyclerView reuses views while you scroll. `getItemViewType` looks like it works because it assigns a new view type per each item which prevents RecyclerView from reusing views. This is not what you want. You want to make sure a) that the data corresponding to each index is always the same and b) that you are displaying correct state while the image is loading which can be achieved by using a placeholder for example. If it's still unclear please post the code from your adapter where you do the creation and binding.

Comment: @ Santanu Sur yes all my ViewHolder Classes are static.

Comment: @Gennadii Saprykin please check my question edited.

Comment: Thanks for adding more info but unfortunately it's still not enough to solve the issue :) Please also add `onBindViewHolder` code. `onCreateViewHolder` method looks correct.

Comment: try to add this to your adapter: `adapter.setHasStableIds(true)` and override method: `public long getItemId(int position){
  return position;
 }`
But in my case the problem was in several types of ViewHolders

Comment: Post the code for `onBindViewHolder()`. Your problem may be there.

Comment: What is the solution for this problem? Anyone?